# Google map Api Share location issue in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, google-maps-api-3

How can I prevent Firefox from asking the user to share their location every time it is requested?

I am using the Google map api. Below is my code to share the location. In Firefox it always asks to share location with the popup below. This happens every time, whether I click on **Share** or **Not Now**.

[image]

Below is my code

```
<% if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{ %>
// opened the share location

if (navigator.geolocation) 
{
    try 
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate);
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}
else 
{
        alert("You location is not available. Please enter your location to continue!");
}
<%}%>

function onPositionUpdate(position) 
{
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    try 
    {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        if (marker == null) 
        {
            alert("Sorry we are not able to update your location.");
        }
        else 
        {
            setTimeout(function () 
                {
                    marker.setPosition(latLng);
                    map.setCenter(latLng);
                    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_latSel').value = lat;
                    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_lngSel').value = lng;
                    geocodePosition(latLng);
                }, 100);
        }
    }
    catch (err) 
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: @RyanGates i am using firefox 24.0

Comment: @RyanGates it is asking for this allow location only once in other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.


Browsers have to ask users permission for sharing your geolocation. It depends of the settings of your browser. If you want to always share your geolocation, in firefox, just [follow this link](http://www.mozilla.org/en/firefox/geolocation/) and go to the last paragraph.

> Location-Aware Browsing is always opt-in in Firefox. No location information is ever sent without your permission. If you wish to disable the feature completely, please follow this set of steps:
>
> - In the URL bar, type about:config
> - Type geo.enabled
> - Double click on the geo.enabled preference
> - Location-Aware Browsing is now disabled

Comment: thanks for this information.
i have done this by storing the Lat and Longitude in cookies and check if Cookies null then allow share location popup to open and set latitude and longitude value in cookies.
Can you please suggest is it correct way or  not?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because your port number changes when you run your website on development server. Goto project properties -> Web -> Servers section: and set Specific Port instead of Auto-assign.

Answer (score 1):

Because by default  setting with webkit and opera browser's normally. For iOS it is necessary to use html5 with -webkit keyword in css some functions doesn't works in other browsers. Basically safari, chrome, opera is used in mobile devices and device features works fine with these.
Firefox browser is not a better option for mobile devices.